# Swift Uncaught exception when saving manageObjectContext

Tags: ios, database, swift, crash, nsmanagedobjectcontext

So in the app that I am developing I have multi threading. There are some thread that call managedObjectContext from appeDelegate and update database and also calling the same managedObjectContext to retrive data.

Sometimes I am getting the following error on this line.

[image]

```
2016-04-01 19:23:41.094 Tamil League[878:219638] -[_CDSnapshot_Matches_ values]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e5c790
2016-04-01 19:23:41.095 Tamil League[878:219638] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_CDSnapshot_Matches_ values]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e5c790'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x245362eb 0x23d02dff 0x2453bab5 0x2453970f 0x24468c88 0x25d31985 0x25d31343 0x25c925fd 0x25c91375 0x25c5e8c1 0x25d1a4d7 0x25d22b47 0x149acab 0x14a44a3 0x25d14929 0x25c5e3b7 0x25c813ab 0xe0e70 0xdd9c4 0x24a3796d 0x24a46ef7 0x24d3a52d 0x24c9beff 0x24c8e2ef 0x24d3c7ed 0x14a55c3 0x149defb 0x14a6ab7 0x14a6909 0x2426ce0d 0x2426c9fc)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I tried to search on net but nothing improved my problem. Does anyone know how to solve this in swift 2.0?

Comment: This crash is about unrecognized selector called on some object. Do you have class like `_CDSnapshot_Matches_` in your project ?

Comment: no I do not have a class with that name